# Unable to edit Properties file loaded via Class.getResource()

Tags: java, properties, classloader

I'm attempting to write a method that will read a properties file using Class.getResource(), make changes to its values, and save the file.

```
public void saveDBConnectionValues(String user, String password, String host, int port) throws IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    Properties dbProperties = new Properties();

    File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("db.properties").toURI());

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f))));     

    dbProperties.load(reader);

    reader.close();

    dbProperties.setProperty("user", user);
    dbProperties.setProperty("pw", password);
    dbProperties.setProperty("host", host);
    dbProperties.setProperty("port", Integer.toString(port));

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f)))

    dbProperties.store(writer, null);

    writer.close();

}
```

My db.properties file is read correctly, but the store method doesn't seem to be working here. Can someone explain why this doesn't work, and what I need to do to get it working?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried explicitely closing the reading chain (BufferedReader and al.) before attempting to write in the same file ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: If this code lives in a webapp, maybe you simply don't have the permissions to write in this particular directory (especially if it's in the webapp structure itself). Can you try with some hard-coded path outside the webapp ?

Comment: In reference to the code above, a call to f.canWrite() produces `true`

Comment: That's a point. How are you testing your code? In the IDE, by exporting to a JAR, or by putting it online in the form of an applet, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource and a file are two different things. A resource is loaded from the class loader, and is found in the classpath. It could be loaded from the file system, or from a jar, or from a socket (or from any other location, depending on the class loader). Writing to a resource doesn't make sense.

If you want to read and write from/to a file, don't use a resource. Use file streams or reader/writer.

Comment: I use getResource() to get the URL so that I can create a File for reading/writing. Is this not good enough? Why?

Comment: Because as soon as you package the classes in a jar, the code will break. If you want to use the file system, use the File IO classes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your snippet locally and it works.
Only consideration is since the resource loaded is the .class file you should look there for the properties file and not where the .java file is located.

To find out the path you could do this

```
final FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); // <-- add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this code when it has been exported to a Jar? Because if you are, a JAR is a form of an archive and therefore the contents can not be amended easily. Basically, you will be able to read files in the JAR, but not write.

Therefore, even if the code is not in the form of a JAR currently, you shouldn't really be trying to do what you are doing. Unfortunately, it is impossible anyway - as I found out after countless attempts myself!

However, it would be nice to hear what exactly the error is. For example, have you caught any exceptions?